# JAVA : How to sum values at the same index in arrays into a single array

Tags: java, arrays, integer

How can I sum values at the same index in arrays into a single array?

We have an array of arrays and are required to write a function that takes in this array and returns a new array that represents the sum of corresponding elements of original array.

If the original array is −

```
[
   [43, 2, 21],[1, 2, 4, 54],[5, 84, 2],[11, 5, 3, 1]
]
```

Then the output should be −

```
[60, 93, 30, 55]
```

I want to get this result with JAVA

I've found javascript code with googling.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-sum-elements-at-the-same-index-in-array-of-arrays-into-a-single-array-javascript

Thank you :)

Comment: Err, what have you tried yourself. We typically HELP you solving problems, but we arent a free code writing service.

Comment: @GhostCat I developed this code myself. So never mind. Also I asked a question on the platform for Q&A.

Comment: Please revisit the comment I gave you two hours ago. I explained to you how things are supposed to work here, when you have "not working code".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*lambda is always a good choice for a short solution*

```
int mat[][] = { {43, 2, 21}, {1, 2, 4, 54}, {5, 84, 2}, {11, 5, 3, 1}};    

int[] array = Arrays.stream(mat)
    .reduce((a1, a2) -> IntStream.range(0, Math.max(a1.length, a2.length))
        .map(i -> i < a1.length && i < a2.length ? a1[i] + a2[i]
            : i < a1.length ? a1[i] : a2[i] ).toArray()).get();
```

*(can handle rows of different lengths)*

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the following code -

```
const arr = [[43, 2, 21],[1, 2, 4, 54],[5, 84, 2],[11, 5, 3, 1]];
const sumArray = (array) => {
   const newArray = [];
   array.forEach(sub => {
      sub.forEach((num, index) => {
         if(newArray[index]){
            newArray[index] += num;
         }else{
            newArray[index] = num;
         }
      });
   });
   return newArray;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Shrish Sharma. Thank you for you answer.
However I want to develop with JAVA not javascript.

Comment: @GhostCat I aksed question with hope that I can find better answer than I know. Sorry if I'm bothering you

Comment: @Julia5049 If you *have* some code ... and it is not working, include in your question here, and tell us where it breaks (see [mcve]). If your code is working, read the help on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and consider asking for a review of your code there.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

        int numbers[][] = {{43, 2, 21},{1, 2, 4, 54},{5, 84, 2},{11, 5, 3, 1}};
        int result[]=new int[4];
        
        for(int a=0;a<4;a++) {
            for(int b=0;b<4;b++) {
                try {
                result[b]+=numbers[a][b];
                }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    
                }
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution will work fine, just that it will take O(n^2) for completion. We can log some error message for cases where the array elements size are not same.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
        int[][] input = {{43, 2, 21},{1, 2, 4, 54},{5, 84, 2},{11, 5, 3, 1}};
        int[] output = new int[input.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length ; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < input.length; j++) {
                try {
                    output[j] = output[j] + input[i][j];
                }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    System.out.println("Size is not same");
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(output));
    }
```

Comment: I think this is wrong. What if input had 5 rows, not 4? The length of the output array is the max length of the inner rows! And note there is no way summing n x m values without reading all those n x m values. There **real** problem is the fact that you dont check for valid length, but use the ignored exception instead. Throwing exceptions is **expensive**.

Answer (score 0):

If you know about the 'Two Pointer Algorithm', you can solve this problem in O(n) time complexity.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] num = {{43, 2, 21, 100},{1, 2, 4, 54},{5,84,2,1,1},{11,5,3,1}};

    int size = 0;

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    while(true){
        if(i == num.length){
            /**
             * insert sum into result array here
             */

            if(i == num.length && j == num[i-1].length)
                break;

            sum = 0;
            i = 0;
            j++;
        }

        if(j < num[i].length) {
            sum += num[i][j];
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```